# Run DiscardServer of Netty 4.0 from downloaded source directory

Tags: java, netty, nio, package

I am trying to run the `DiscardServer` module of a Maven compiled program called Netty, which I have downloaded as source code.  I'm using a GNU/Linux command line terminal to try and follow the instructions in the manual http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html.

I'm assuming I should run `DiscardServer` in directory example/src/main/java, but when I move to that directory and type

```
$ java -cp "~/norbert/netty-master/all/target/netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:~/norbert/netty-master/all/target/netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar" io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

the response is "Error: Could not find or load main class io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer"

I know the class can be run from a source directory somehow, because

```
$ java io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

produces

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:492)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:484)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Having downloaded the binary version netty-4.0.13.Final in addition, I was able to start the discard server in directory netty-4.0.13.Final/jar as follows:

```
 $ java -cp "netty-example-4.0.13.Final.jar:netty-transport-4.0.13.Final.jar:netty-common-4.0.13.Final.jar:netty-buffer-4.0.13.Final.jar" io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

How can I run the DiscardServer from directory example/src/main/java or the relevant source directory, though?  Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

inside the example folder, you should run:

```
mvn install
```

then

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer"
```